# Wordpress Duplicator from MAMP to local LAMP server - Links broken

Tags: html, wordpress

I developed a Wordpress site locally using MAMP.
I'm trying to transfer it on my home server to show to the client, so I used the plugin "Duplicator".
Everything seemed to work fine but all the links are now broken.
I put the .zip archive and the installer.php inside a folder inside the "html" folder of apache and run installed.php from the browser.

Comment: EDIT: fixed on my own, just went to dashboard -> settings -> permalinks and changed it to "simple", then hit save.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the 'duplicator' plugin, but when you transfer a Wordpress site to a new server, you usually have to do three things.

1. Edit the wp_options table and change the `siteurl` and `home` field to the URL of the new site.
2. Update the wp-config.php file to have the correct settings for the new server.
3. Use a search and replace tool to bulk replace the old URL with the new URL in all your posts and pages. The best tool I have found is to install wp-cli (http://wp-cli.org/) and then run:

   `wp search-replace oldurl.com newurl.com`

You obviously need to use `wp search-replace` carefully, as you could mess up a lot of posts if you do it wrong. So obviously keep a backup around.